# Create a main abstract View in android

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, abstraction

I have a RelativeLayout which contains custom image/text views, all of those share many methods in common (which are currently gathered in an interface) and are implemented the same in all classes.

I want to minimize the amount of overlapping code between the existing views. I know there is no multiple inheritance in Java, but is there some way to create a view to hold all similar code, and to inherit from Image/Text/Layout.. views?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make a custom view and let it extend from View and have all you subclasses of view extend from that View. There is as far as i know, no easy way out (e.g. multiple inheritance)

Comment: I thought about it, but if I extend View then I will lose all of the support for say ImageView, causing me to implement all the logic used there all over again, am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a similar thing by having a separate class, let's call it `ViewHelper`. This class has only public static methods that perform the things you want to have in interface implementations. And I am calling this class from each implementation. It's not a perfect solution as I still have some duplicated code, but I am only calling a public static method from each implementation, while I have the implementation in a single class - `ViewHelper`.

I'll try below to describe what I mean by some general code examples.

The interface:

```
public interface IView {
    public void someMeth(View view);
}
```

The `ViewHelper`:

```
public class ViewHelper {
    public static void someMethImpl(View view) {
        /**
         * here you'll have the implementation if the implementation can be
         * abstracted to a View
         */
    }
    public static void someMethImpl(ImageView view) {
        /**
         * here you'll have the implementation if the implementation can be
         * abstracted to an ImageView
         */
    }
}
```

And then for each custom view/viewgroup class:

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements IView {

    /// constructors

    @Override
    public void someMeth(View view) {
        ViewHelper.someMethImpl(this);
    }
}
```

or:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView implements IView {

    // constructors

    @Override
    public void someMeth(View view) {
        ViewHelper.someMethImpl(this);
    }

}
```

or:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView implements IView {

    // constructors

    @Override
    public void someMeth(View view) {
        ViewHelper.someMethImpl(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: that seems like a good approach for me, what would you do if there are also variables which are similar in those classes? like a Point to indicate where the view is located inside its parent?

Comment: It depends on the implementation details, but if implementations are similar, send that object in a new static helper method and have there the same work. This discussion would be more productive if you would share some example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple `Java class` to hold your logic and write your code there, and have an interface to do the callback logic, route your interface callback to the class you created. I've given a sample implementation/pseudo code below.

```
public class SampleLogicClass implements SampleInterface{    

 public sample(){
 }

 @Override
 public void callLogic1(){
 // Write something
 }

 @Override
 public void callLogic2(){
 // Write something
 }

 public void registerInterface(SampleInterface interface){
   sampleInterface = interface;
 }

 public interface SampleInterface(){
  void callLogic1();
  void callLogic2();
 }
}
```

You could also do the same thing from a RelativeLayout/AnyView/ViewGroup etc. Just register for the callback using the sample registration for the interface and implement your logic. If you could provide some more information/code it would be easy to help you out.

Comment: The problem is that all my logic is the same at all classes, and I have to implement it in the same fashion in all of them. A thing I would like to avoid.

Comment: all you have to do is create a singleton for your logic and call it from any class with Singleton.getInstance().callsomeMethod();